# Visit Visa for my mother

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am a doctor working in the NHS. I want to apply for a visitor visa for my mother. She is staying alone and manages her livelihood by the income from our agricultural land. She is not maintaining bank statement. The agriculture land is in my name and she doesn’t have any properties in India in her name.

I am very worried that there are high chances of her visa rejection. Please tell me what should I do as I am the only daughter so I want my mother to spend some time with me in the UK. My questions are:

1. Can I produce a joint bank statement of myself and my mom in India
2. Should I mention that my mother is the one who is taking care of my
   agriculture land?
3. Anything else should I need to mention in her visa
   application?

Comment: A few questions, the answers to which may help your application somewhat - 1. who will be looking after the agricultural interests while your mother is visiting you, 2. is your mother actually co-named on the Indian bank account you propose to produce a bank statement for, and 3. how does your mother pay taxes and more importantly *prove* she pays taxes in India?  A potentially difficult fourth question - are you earning money from the land in India while in the UK, and if so are you declaring it as income in the UK?

Comment: 1)my grand parents 2) no I am yet to make a joint account 3)why should she pay taxes she has nothing in her name 4)No my mother and my grandparents are living with the money we are getting from the land

Comment: Your mother has very tenuous ties to India and with such a situation getting entry clearance to the UK may prove difficult.

Comment: I agree with @user56513 here - your mother basically has no ties to India, and no proof that she can support herself or afford her trip.  Creating a joint account now will simply work against you, as it needs to show a decent history of deposits, and you need to show where those deposits come from etc.  This will be an extremely difficult application.

Comment: So,there is no way My mom could stay with me,????

Comment: I don’t want my mom to go into depression since she is staying alone without me.                                                   .                                                                                           .                                                                                      p.s My father died 26 years before

Comment: Someone please help me...hope u can understand my situation

Comment: No one can help you here, but yourself.  `she is staying alone without me` Another reason she might be refused. Why don't you transfer the land in her name, so she will have some ties back to India which might help a bit.

Comment: We are helping you by telling you the truth instead of giving you false hope. A suggestion would be to transfer the land into your mothers name. Open a bank account for her so she transfers the proceeds from the farm consistently into the back account so she has a history of transactions. After doing this for six months she can apply. This is just a **suggestion**. From your statement it **appears** to me your mother will not be a genuine visitor to UK. It **appears** You actually want her to come and stay with you. I am not judging you, just noting my observations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply I will try to transfer land documents to my mothers name

Comment: If your mother doesn't function alone, then you might want to look at a permanent [Dependent Relative visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/parents-grandparents-and-other-dependants-set08/parents-grandparents-and-other-dependants-set08)

Comment: Is that possible???? Her Health condition is absolutely fine now..